# Running Jersey examples with Maven

Tags: java, maven, jersey

Given the repo https://github.com/jersey/jersey cloned locally:

What maven command do you need to build and run the demos in `/examples`?

My assumption is you should be able to clone the repo and have all the examples work without changing anything in any of the `*.pom` files. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you do not need to edit anything. Follow these steps:

1. `git clone git@github.com:jersey/jersey.git`
2. `cd jersey`
3. `mvn clean install -DskipTests`
4. `cd examples/helloworld-webapp/`
5. `mvn clean compile exec:java`
6. open: http://localhost:8080/helloworld-webapp/helloworld

If you dislike to build the unstable bleeding edge you can checkout a release tag:

1.1 (right after clone, or later in the parent directory): `git checkout tags/2.22.2`

the other steps are the same.

Comment: Wow, awesome. I see now that I wasn't completing the `install` phase because the tests were failing. Would that be your natural choice, to skip the tests initially when building a whole repo with Maven?

Comment: If i build the trunk - yes :) But for the tests it could be, that you have to do some setup... maybe to much work to only start the examples.